I can format the BitLocker encrypted without unlocking it. But I saw lots of articles on internet which say I can't do it?
I can format the BitLocker encrypted drive without unlocking it. But I saw lots of articles on internet which say I can't do it. Is there any damage to my drive if I format it on locked state? Looking forward to your reply.

BitLocker has two modes of operation:

Software mode, where all encryption is handled by the OS (CPU) and it all looks just like regular data to the disk.

Hardware mode, where the OS enables OPAL encryption mode on the disk and everything is handled by the disk's firmware.


Older Windows versions used to activate the hardware mode (OPAL) whenever supported, e.g. in most SSDs, but now software mode is the default.
In software mode, the encrypted data is still stored as normal data and can be overwritten or erased at any time; the disk doesn't know any better.
When OPAL is in use, however, the disk's firmware does actually lock all access until the password is provided – until that's done, all read and write attempts just return an I/O error instead of showing the 'ciphertext', similar to what you'd have with the traditional "ATA password" feature. (Though, unlike the old "ATA password", the data is also encrypted.)
(Erasing an OPAL-encrypted disk without the password usually requires the "PSID", i.e. an erase-only password, that's printed on the sticker.)
This is not a BitLocker thing specifically – it works the same even if OPAL is activated by LUKS (cryptsetup), or by sedutil, or ESET Endpoint Encryption, or any other software.

Excellent! Thank you for your reply.
So is hardware mode safer than software mode?
Besides, what is OPAL?  Opal Storage Specification?
